# Sync multiple properties on state between React app and Firebase database using re-base

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The re-base documentation is quite clear on the matter when it comes to syncing one property of your react app's state with firebase: https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base#syncstateendpoint-options

It says to use syncState in the componentDidMount method of your component like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  base.syncState(`shoppingList`, {
    context: this,
    state: 'items',
    asArray: true
  });
}
```

I want to sync two different properties, so 'shoppingList; and 'weeklyBudget'. I tried to duplicate the statement like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  base.syncState(`shoppingList`, {
    context: this,
    state: 'items'
  });
  base.syncState(`weeklyBudget`, {
    context: this,
    state: 'budget'
  });

}
```

But the console just throws the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Order`.

How do I could sync multiple properties on state between React app and Firebase database using re-base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `asArray: true` to the object right after `context: this,` you should be fine.

It works like this for me. I am not satisfied with this code at all myself because I have seven blocks that connect to different endpoints. An alternative might be to use fetch and resolve via `Promise.all([x, y, z]).then()`