# How can I sync my data between a React frontend and Firestore backend?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

If I have some user that I create and I give them some currency, what is the best way to sync the data between my firestore and the frontend? Like for example I wanna display their currency on the screen at all times and it'll be updating if they do some task, should I just update the firestore first and make that frontend data always depend on the firestore? Or how would I possibly do this?

Have done a bunch of research but I'm not really sure what a good way to do something like this would be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Tay Baye, please let me know if the below information was helpful

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you are looking for the possible way to sync data between firestore and reactjs frontend and so if you want to  auto-update the data in your react application -when something in your database is updated you need some kind of socket server for that. You can fire an event from your backend, and subscribe to it in your frontend, and then perform a query to fetch the data.
You could look into a websockets library such as [socket.io](https://socket.io/) although this will need configuration server-side.

Also referring to the second line of query you have for

> if you should just update the firestore first and make that frontend data always depend on the firestore

most people would recommend developing the frontend first,but that is again case dependent .This is especially true if you are talking about a site or application that depends heavily on the user experience. In most cases, it's easier to work the backend to meet the needs of the frontend instead of following the process in reverse.
I would recommend you to have a look at the below examples with similar implementations for a better understanding of the concept.

- [Sync multiple properties on state between react app and firebase
  database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321024/sync-multiple-properties-on-state-between-react-app-and-firebase-database-using)
- [How to sync data between users and reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254883/how-to-sync-data-between-users-reactjs)
- [Getting data from backend after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006054/i-am-getting-data-from-firebase-after-page-refresh-in-react)